# Connect crystal to low jitter clock generator

Tags: oscillator, packages

I have this TSX-3225 25MHz crystal. It has two outputs (pin3 and pin1).
I want to connect it to the CDCM61001 low jitter clock generator. The CDCM61001 has one crystal input (XIN).

- Should I connect one of the two outputs to XIN and tie the other one to ground?
- the TSX-3225 has two unconnected pins (pin2 and pin4) does it matter if I tie them to ground or let float?

Link for the CDCM61001: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cdcm61001.pdf?ts=1603113603064&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCDCM61001

Link for the TSX-3225 25MHz: https://support.epson.biz/td/api/doc_check.php?dl=brief_TSX-3225&lang=en

Comment: Two pins are connected to case. If you ground them (or even one of them) you can reduce coupling to the outside world - a good thing. Grounding the case can also cause a very small shift of nominal frequency due to the slightly larger capacitance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Should I connect one of the two outputs to XIN and tie the other one
> to ground?*

Just take a little time and read the data sheet: -

[image]

> *the TSX-3225 has two unconnected pins (pin2 and pin4) does it matter
> if I tie them to ground or let float?*

Connect them to ground/0 volts.

Comment: It says "calculating the right capacitor value". So do I need somehow a capacitor inbetween? I thought capacitance is a bad thing for crystals.

Comment: No, you need to choose a crystal that inherently has a parallel capacitance of 10 pF. It should be in the data sheet but, crystal data sheets are notoriously ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for your insights!

Comment: The data sheet you linked is quite ambiguous in that it doesn't state whether the device is series or parallel resonant at the operating frequency. If you are not overly concerned about a slight frequency error (maybe 1 kHz) you can pick a series resonant crystal into the circuit and you might find it runs a little high in frequency.

Comment: 1KHz would not be a problem. In most datasheets there is a load and a shunt capacitance stated. The load capacitance is the important value right? So load capacitance has to be 10 pF?

Comment: Load capacitance only applies to non-parallel resonant crystals. The shunt capacitance inside the crystal chosen should be around 10 pF. But, it'll probably work just fine if you are not bothered about crystal accuracy. If you want the full run-down [try reading this](http://www.stades.co.uk/XTAL%20Oscillator/XTAL%20Oscillator.html)